# Как правильно переделать программу со статическими массивами на динамические

Tags: c++

Имеется программа, которая создаёт квадратную матрицу порядка **N**, переставляет i-тую строку на первое место матрицы, а все остальные строки подвигает вниз. Вот собственно и код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#define N 5
using namespace std;

int main() {

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    int ctarr[N][N], helper[N], repl, method;
    srand(time(0));

    cout << "Как желаете заполнить массив?\n1. Вручную\n2. С помощью случайных чисел\n";
    cin >> method;
    switch (method) {
    case 1:
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                cout << "Введите " << j + 1 << "-й элемент " << i + 1 << "-й строки: ";
                cin >> ctarr[i][j];
            }
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                ctarr[i][j] = rand();
            }
        }
        break;
    default: break;
    }

    cout << "\nИсходный массив:\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            cout << ctarr[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "\nКакую строку переставить? ";
    cin >> repl;
    repl--;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        helper[i] = ctarr[repl][i];
    }

    for (int i = repl; i > 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            ctarr[i][j] = ctarr[i - 1][j];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        ctarr[0][i] = helper[i];
    }

    cout << "\n\nПолученный массив\n\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            cout << ctarr[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Нужно переделать её так, чтобы место *статических* массивов использовать *динамические* типа: `int* ctarr = (int*)malloc(N*sizeof(int));`

Никак не получается что бы не пробовал :(

Comment: Почему malloc, если C++?

Comment: Я новичок в cpp, увидел это в какой то статье, попробовал - заработало)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`malloc` пришёл из Си, в C++ используется `type* a = new type;`- для одной переменной и `type* a = new type[n];` - для выделения массива, где `type` - нужный тип (например `int`), `n` - размер выделяемой памяти и `delete a;` / `delete[] a;` соответственно для освобождения выделенной памяти.

```
const int N = 5;

int** createMatr(int rows, int columns) {
    // массив указателей, которые будут ссылаться на начало строк
    int **m = new int*[rows];
    // сама матрица будет одномерным массивом
    m[0] = new int[rows*columns];
    // размечаем начало строк
    for (int i = 1; i < rows; i++) {
        m[i] = m[i - 1] + columns;
    }
    return m;
}

void deleteMatr(int **m) {
    // удаляем массив для матрицы
    delete[] m[0];
    // удаляем массив для указателей на строки
    delete[] m;
}

int main() {
    int **ctarr = createMatr(N, N);
    int *helper = new int[N];
    /* остальной код без изменений */
    deleteMatr(ctarr);
    delete[] helper;
    return 0;
}
```

Иллюстрация работы функции createMatr для матрицы 5x4
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]